# Is there a way to deal with CORS without having access to the backend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I think I've gone through 100 Stackoverflow posts about enabling CORS with AngularJS. Most of them reference adding headers to the API. 
Is there anyway to solve this issue if you don't have direct access to edit the API you're using?

Comment: Why you don't want to add headers ?

Comment: @Thanigainathan many third-party APIs were designed for clients other than the browser, which typically don't enforce CORS (you won't find it in Java's HttpClient or curl, for example). Using them from a browser requires headers they simply omitted. Same goes for older APIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need CORS headers but the original API doesn't provide them, you can set up a small proxy server and call through that. Using HAProxy or Nginx, you can restrict the destinations to just the API and add headers on the way through. You may also be able to set up the proxy on a path under the site's origin and avoid headers altogether.

To set up your own CORS proxy with HAProxy, you [just need to add a few config lines](http://johntdyer.com/haproxy/2015/03/05/dynamic-access-control-allow-origin-header-in-haproxy.html):

```
listen http-in
    mode http
    listen *:80

    # Add CORS headers when Origin header is present
    capture request header origin len 128
    http-response add-header Access-Control-Allow-Origin %[capture.req.hdr(0)] if { capture.req.hdr(0) -m found }
    rspadd Access-Control-Allow-Headers:\ Origin,\ X-Requested-With,\ Content-Type,\ Accept  if { capture.req.hdr(0) -m found }
```

I prefer to use HAProxy, [because it's incredibly resource-efficient](http://www.haproxy.org/10g.html).

With Nginx, [you need a little bit more configuration](http://oskarhane.com/avoid-cors-with-nginx-proxy_pass/) as the headers and proxy are set up separately:

```
upstream api_server {
    server apiserver.com;
}

server {
        charset UTF-8;
        listen 80;
        root /home/web/myclient;
        index index.html;
        server_name myclient.com;

        location /api/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://api_server/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri;
        }
}
```

Both examples are copied from the linked blog posts in case they ever vanish. I did not write either of them.

Comment: would `crossorigin.me` be an alternative to using `jsonp`?

Comment: JSONP isn't terribly good practice, while setting up a proxy gives you some visibility into what's being called without changing your code. Considering how easy it is to set up nginx or haproxy and add the necessary headers (plus the fact haproxy requires very little hardware), I'd go that route every time.

Comment: @ssube but is CORS not there as a security mechanism, hence using these proxies is breaching this security, or am I misunderstanding this whole question?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald in the absence of CORS headers, the browser implements a very restrictive, naive requirement that the origin match exactly. The headers were introduced to allow a whitelist of friendly domains, but not everybody sends those headers. Setting up a proxy that allows access to a single destination (the API) and adds headers to whitelist a single origin (your site) is pretty safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Mozilla Firefox there is an Add-On called "cors everywhere". If you install it you can activate and disable it on every site you want and it works like a charm.

Comment: Requiring an extension just to make your site work won't go over very well with users.

Comment: Of course! I think he has this problem only when testing on localhost. I had the same problem and in production it works without addon.